# Android: convertView in ListView is always null

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

I want to use ViewHolder pattern in ListView (I know about RecyclerView but I want it in ListView!!!).

I created it but I noticed that convertView in getView() is always null. Each call getView(). What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ScheduleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater lInflater;
    private List<ScheduleSubject> scheduleListItems;

    public ScheduleListAdapter(Context context, List<ScheduleSubject> scheduleListItems) {
        this.scheduleListItems = scheduleListItems;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return scheduleListItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return scheduleListItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name, place;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_item_show, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.schedule_item_name_textView);
            viewHolder.place = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.schedule_item_place_textView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ScheduleSubject scheduleListItem = getScheduleListItem(position);
        viewHolder.number.setText(String.valueOf(scheduleListItem.getLessonNumber()));
        viewHolder.name.setText(scheduleListItem.getName());
        viewHolder.place.setText(scheduleListItem.getPlace());

        return convertView;
    }

    public ScheduleSubject getScheduleListItem(int position) {
        return ((ScheduleSubject) getItem(position));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add logcat to your question.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this line

```
ViewHolder viewHolder;
```

with this one :

```
Holder viewHolder;
```

and this one :

```
viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

with this one :

```
viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
```